# Python - convert binary string to little nibble hex string

Tags: python

Input:

0000001101110010000000100000011110000000100000111000000111110010

Output should be:

302720700838182f

In perl I can do it like this:

unpack("h*", pack("B*", "0000001101110010000000100000011110000000100000111000000111110010"));

Comment: No, this is high nibble first

Comment: That would give me 0x3720207808381f2

Comment: Right, retracted my duplicated flag

Comment: Your example doesn't make sense to me. Just look at the last 8 bits; how do you go from `11110010` to `82`? Guessing at what you mean by "little nibble", `2f` would make sense;

Comment: "302720700838182f" is correct sorry

Comment: Im not sure how to get this result, I have a perl script that does this and gets that response. Im not sure how to write the code or I would.

Comment: Why is this tagged perl? Your title only mentions python...

Comment: Edited to reflect perl portion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"".join([ ("%02x" % int(x,2))[::-1] for x in re.findall(r'.{8}', bits) ])
```

I'm sure there's a nicer way, but it works: extract 8 bits at a time from the input, use `int(..., 2)` to parse them as binary, then format as hex, then swap the nibbles (`[::-1]`), then stick it all back together.

alternatively, if you find the use of `re` here ugly:

```
"".join([ ("%02x" % int(bits[i:i+8],2) )[::-1] for i in range(0, len(bits), 8) ])
```